# ¿Colorear DatagridView en forma de tablero de Ajedrez C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagridview

Muy Buenas lo que busco hacer es generar  un tablero de ajedrez en un DataGridView solamente proporcionándole el tamaño mxn  y colorear cada celda de forma intercalada el problema que tengo es que se repite la misma secuencia de intercalado en cada fila y lo que se termina pintando es una especie de código de barrras repitiendo la misma secuencia.

**Cabe resaltar que tengo un método específico para generar la matriz mxn y no afecta en el pintado.**

> **Codigo que empleo**

```
int tamaño = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tamaño = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    formatogrilla(dataGridView1);
}

private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.RowCount; j++)
        {
            if ((i % 2) == 0)
            {
                dgv[i, j].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            else
            {
                dgv[i, j].Style.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, seria bueno que dieras un voto positivo a las respuestas que consideres útiles y marques como aceptada la que mejor te haya parecido, gracias

Comment: ambas respuestas me sirvieron pero termine aplicando la primera por el tiempo de respuesta aunque la de usted se ve que esta mas completa y explicada gracias

Comment: Bueno si la mía te fue útil te agradecería tu voto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me disculpo por la identación:

Este algoritmo es para dibujar el tablero de ajedrez.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.RowCount; j++) {

            if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
                dgv[i, j].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
            } else {
                dgv[i, j].Style.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: El codigo solo no basta debes explicarlo

Comment: muchas gracias revisare  su funcionamiento y lo implemetare  tuve percances para revisar la respuesta a  tiempo

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo está solución:

```
if(e.RowIndex % 2 == 0 && e.ColumnIndex % 2 == 0)
{
   e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
else if(e.RowIndex % 2 == 1 && e.ColumnIndex % 2 == 1)
{
   e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Resulta que el mismo **evento Cell_Formatting** nos da la solución. Dentro de un **DataGridView** cada celda tiene un índice de fila y uno de columna. Por tanto usaremos estos índices para crear nuestro tablero. Si el índice de la fila y la columna son pares pintamos de negro todas las celdas que cumplan esta condición. Igualmente si el índice de la columna y fila de la celda son impares pintamos de negro estás celdas. De esta forma garantizamos la alternancia en los colores, sin usar ciclos. El mismo evento es el encargado de pintar el tablero, de esta forma nos ahorramos dos **ciclos for**, ya que el propio evento recorre cada celda y va coloreando según la condición que le ponemos.